# "quoteBaseGrandTotal is not defined" error during Checkout in Shipping Block

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, ce-1.9.1.0, prototype-js, onestepcheckout

In my magento website running ver. 1.9.1.0 when I add any product to cart and go to checkout then the checkout page seems fine, but on the checkout page when I select "Shipping Methods" radio button then I get error in the console saying "quoteBaseGrandTotal is not defined".

Below is the website product-list link, add product to cart(by drag-drop), click on "Checkout" and check it yourselves:
http://115.112.143.170/ECO/mag/cookpack/cookpack-recipes/diet/paleo-diet.html

Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

It's very urgent.

Comment: Do you have any customization in checkout process or, in shipping method?

Comment: I have used "onestepcheckout" and moved some of it's blocks around changing their position like "review" block showing before the totals, and some custom css for styling purposes only.  It works the first time when page is loaded, but when I select shipping then it causes error in console.

Comment: @Rahul: I have posted the link of product-list page so you can add it to cart and go to checkout, may be you get idea of what is going wrong, I don't think prototypejs has issue, but it could be due to specific block not getting called by js(when it is hardcoded), can you take a look and let me know ?

Comment: Did it work before you made customizations?